# Replacing terms of an exact sequence by quotients

Tags: group-theory, exact-sequence

First time questioner here. 
I have found myself perplexed by a problem on exact sequences. I have thoroughly scoured the internet for help but my searches have come up empty. Given a long exact sequence of groups

$0 \to A \to B \to C \to D \to E \to F \to 0$

I want to know if i can use this to create a new short exact sequence

$0 \to B/A \to D/C \to F/E \to 0$

My main problem with this is, for example, in my long exact sequence $A \to 0$ in C since the kernel from $B \to C$ is the image of $A \to B$, so in this case I'm not sure that my idea of reducing to the short exact sequence of quotients would be justified. I find it odd that there was little to nothing about this online, which leads me to believe that I may be very wrong in this case. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As $C$ is not a submodule of $D$, what even does $D/C$ mean?

Comment: Sorry, when i say something like $D/C$ I associate this to be the quotient of $D$ by the image of $C$ in D.

Comment: It is not hard to manufacture counterexamples.

Comment: @H.Hughes if so, then what does $F/E$ end up as?

Comment: Thats a very good point, i guess i need to construct more examples before trying to come up with an all round solution